# How to return to Root View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, navigation

I am currently working on an app which presents a screen modally and another custom progress indicator modally. Is it possible to return to the root View Controller seamlessly?

Home -> screen1-> screen2(Custom progressIndicator)

I want to dismiss the custom progressIndicator (and the screen presented modally) and return to my home (root) View Controller in one go.

```
 self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to dismiss presented model then you can pop all the pushed view controllers. As presented model would not be in the stack of the navigation.

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {});
```

Then you can pop to base view controller.

```
self.navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(true);
```

Answer (score 9):

If you use `presentViewController`, you can use

```
[self.view.window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

to go back to root view. It works on IOS9.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4**

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {});
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3 this will work:

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {});
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true);
```