# Come back to the tabBarController, swift

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uistoryboardsegue, unwind-segue

Currently on my viewController : **Upload**, my button send the data to my database only if all the information are filled out, and I come back to the preview view (table View) with : 
`self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)`

I would like, if it is possible, to come back to my main view on the [tabBarController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLmBp.png). I tried many things, like directly on the storyboard with **Present modally segue to "TabBar controller"**, but I come back to the TabBar without sending my data to the database and without checking in the information are filled out..

**How can I do it?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITabBarController` has a property `selectedIndex` with which you can switch the selected tab. So on completion after dismissing the UploadViewController you can run:

```
self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0 // Index to select
```

It would probably be best to create a delegate for your UploadViewController to fire a function to do all the work in your previewVC on API call completion.

Comment: you are the best!! It works like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

(Super late response...in case someone has similar questions, presumably in later version of Swift, such as mine which is Swift 5, iOS 13.2). Steps:

1. Be sure to set an id for your UITabBarController storyboard, e.g. "TabBarViewController"
2. Next, add the following to an action that has already been connected to a button:

`let ID_TABBAR = "TabBarViewCOntroller"`

```
@IBAction func returnToTabbar(_ sender: Any) {
        let tabBarController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier:ID_TABBAR) as! UITabBarController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tabBarController, animated:true)
}
```

Referenced from [one of the responses from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52198347/6036809).

**Update:** In case your Tab Bar View Controller also happens to be the root view controller, the two lines of the code in the `returnToTabbar` method above can be:

```
self.dismiss(animated:true, completion:nil);
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated:true);
```

(ref.: See answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46546098/6036809), for Swift4 but works just fine in Swift5)